Paypal Webhooks not triggering
I have set up webhooks for subscription events in the PayPal sandbox environment. The webhooks are functioning correctly when I cancel a subscription using the PayPal API; I receive the corresponding webhook notifications without any issues.
However, I am encountering a problem when I cancel a subscription directly from the PayPal dashboard. In this case, I do not receive any webhook notifications, and there are no records of these events in the webhook event log or any error logs on PayPal.
I have tested the webhooks on webhook.site and the webhooks are being received from the express(nodejs) called api
Screenshot Webhooks received when cancelled from the node js api
